# How to use Docker with Vue.js?

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, vuejs2

How can I use docker with vue.js?

I haven't found much documentation on this, I don't even know where to start.

apart from this I don't find anything else: http://vuetips.com/use-docker-containers

Comment: see https://hub.docker.com/r/rflavien/vue-cli/ or https://github.com/ebiven/docker-vue-cli or https://github.com/zimdo/docker-vuejs

Comment: Why you need to user docker with Vue? Why not vue alone?

Comment: @Bunyk so maybe I can just run my database in a docker container and use its output for working with vue.js

Comment: @CodingMcCodington You could just run `npm run build` anywhere (even inside Docker container) (if you configured your build process, `vue-cli` could do that for you) and then put everything from `dist/` folder somewhere from where webserver could serve it.